# How to set all values in listview android

Tags: android

I have created a listview. All values are retrieved from the json response but only the last values were displayed in the list.what to do for displaying the all values in list view.

```
 SixFragment.movieList = new ArrayList<Movie1>();

 for (int i1 = 0; i1 < jsonArray3.length(); i1++) {
     try {
         JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray3.getJSONObject(i1);
         review_rating = jsonObject.optString("review_rating").toString();
         username_rate = jsonObject.optString("username").toString();
         review_title = jsonObject.optString("review_title").toString();
         review_desc = jsonObject.optString("review_desc").toString();
         sleep = jsonObject.optString("Sleep").toString();
         location = jsonObject.optString("Location").toString();
         service = jsonObject.optString("Service").toString();
         rooms = jsonObject.optString("Rooms").toString();
         cleanliness = jsonObject.optString("Cleanliness").toString();
         userimage1 = jsonObject.optString("user_image").toString();

         Movie1 movie = new Movie1();


                    movie.setRate_userimage(userimage1);
                    movie.setreview_rating(review_rating);
                    movie.setusername_rate(username_rate);
                    movie.setreview_title(review_title);
                    movie.setreview_desc(review_desc);
                    movie.setsleep(sleep);
                    movie.setlocation(location);
                    movie.setservice(service);
                    movie.setraterooms(rooms);
                    movie.setcleanliness(cleanliness);

                    SixFragment.movieList.add(movie);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
```

This is my fragment page:

```
public class SixFragment extends Fragment{
    public static String userimage;
    public static String review_rating;
    public static String username_rate;
    public static String  review_title;
    public static String review_desc;
    public static String  sleep;
    public static String  location;
    public static String  service;
    public static String  rooms;
    public static String  cleanliness;
    public static ArrayList stringArray;
    public static ArrayList<Movie1> movieList= new ArrayList<Movie1>();;

    ListView listView;
    Reviewadapter reviewadapter;

    public SixFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_six, container, false);
        ListView list=(ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.six_listView);



        return v;
    }

}
```

This logcat error`

```
  E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main


Process: com.airstar.abservetech.airstar, PID: 27390
                                                                                     java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                         at com.airstar.abservetech.adapter.Reviewadapter.getCount(Reviewadapter.java:160)
                                                                                         at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:488)
                                                                                         at com.airstar.abservetech.airstar.SixFragment.onCreateView(SixFragment.java:75)
                                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
```

`

Review adapter

```
    public class Reviewadapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private final List<Movie1> movieItems;
    public SixFragment context;

    OneFragment Fragment;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    public Reviewadapter(SixFragment context, List<Movie1> movieItems) {
        this.context = context;
        this.movieItems = movieItems;
        this.Fragment=Fragment;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sixlist,parent,false);

            CircleImageView profile_image = (CircleImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
            TextView rate_username = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rate_username);
            RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
            TextView rate_title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rate_title);
            TextView rate_description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rate_description);
            RatingBar ratingBar_sleep = (RatingBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar_sleep);
            RatingBar ratingBar_location = (RatingBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar_location);
            RatingBar ratingBar_service = (RatingBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar_service);
            RatingBar ratingBar_clearness = (RatingBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar_clearness);
            RatingBar ratingBar_rooms = (RatingBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar_rooms);

            final Movie1 m = movieItems.get(position);


//            Glide.with(context)
//                    .load(m.getRate_userimage())
//                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
//                    .into(profile_image);
            URL url = null;
            String image=m.getRate_userimage();
            try {
                url = new URL(image);
                InputStream is = null;
//                Bitmap bitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                //create imageview dynamically

                Glide.with(context).load(String.valueOf(url)).into(profile_image);

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //Glide.with(context).load(String.valueOf(url)).into(profile_image);

            if (m.getusername_rate()!=null)
            {
                if (!m.getusername_rate().equals("null"))
                {
                    rate_username.setText(m.getusername_rate());
                }}

            if (m.getreview_rating()!=null)
            {
                if (!m.getreview_rating().equals("null"))
                {
                    ratingBar.setRating(Float.parseFloat(m.getreview_rating()));

                }}


            if (m.getsleep()!=null)
            {
                if (!m.getsleep().equals("null"))
                {
                    ratingBar_sleep.setRating(Float.parseFloat(m.getsleep()));

                }}


        }


        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return movieItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return movieItems.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
}
```

Comment: see my answer @sri..!!

Comment: see @jankigadhiya 's answer, thats the right way to do..

Comment: Guessing on your use of `static`, I assume you don't know what it means?

Comment: Also, we need a [mcve], but you are missing the `Reviewadapter` code in your question

Comment: Now i have add the review adapter coading @cricket

Comment: Your error tells you that `return movieItems.size();` has thrown a NullPointerException because you have given the adapter an uninitialized arraylist in the constructor.

Comment: what to do for rectifiying that error

Comment: initialize the movielist inside your fragment before setting the adapter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Your Fragment make your list **static**:

```
public class SixFragment extends Fragment{

      // Your code
//------------DO THIS------------------///

public static List<Movie1> movieList = new ArrayList<Movie1>();


public SixFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

//Your code

}
```

**Rest of the code in your fragment will be as it is.**

Change your JSON loop like this :

```
SixFragment.movieList = new ArrayList<Movie1>();
    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < jsonArray3.length(); i1++) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray3.getJSONObject(i1);
            review_rating = jsonObject.optString("review_rating").toString();
            username_rate = jsonObject.optString("username").toString();
            review_title = jsonObject.optString("review_title").toString();
            review_desc = jsonObject.optString("review_desc").toString();
            sleep = jsonObject.optString("Sleep").toString();
            location = jsonObject.optString("Location").toString();
            service = jsonObject.optString("Service").toString();
            rooms = jsonObject.optString("Rooms").toString();
            cleanliness = jsonObject.optString("Cleanliness").toString();
            userimage1 = jsonObject.optString("user_image").toString();

            Movie1 movie = new Movie1();


            movie.setRate_userimage(userimage1);
            movie.setreview_rating(review_rating);
            movie.setusername_rate(username_rate);
            movie.setreview_title(review_title);
            movie.setreview_desc(review_desc);
            movie.setsleep(sleep);
            movie.setlocation(location);
            movie.setservice(service);
            movie.setraterooms(rooms);
            movie.setcleanliness(cleanliness);

            SixFragment.movieList.add(movie);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: if i do like this means its show null pointer exception in fragment
at the place  reviewadapter=new Reviewadapter(SixFragment.this, movieList);
       list.setAdapter(reviewadapter);

Comment: no jsonloop is in activity and fragment is present inside that activity

Comment: Write `public static ArrayList<Movie1> movieList= new ArrayList<Movie1>();`  where you have declared it...  in Your `SixFragment` @sri..!!

Comment: Whether or not the list/data is in the same file or not, you can either pass the list or the json string into the Fragment as an argument. Overall, messing with static variables isn't encouraged for sharing data across processes

Comment: i  have declared public static ArrayList<Movie1> movieList= new ArrayList<Movie1>(); in six fragment @janki gadhiya